# Where can the AWS Convertible Reserved Instance ExchangeId be used?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-reserved-instances

When you make an AWS Convertible Reserved Instance Exchange request, you are provided with an ExchangeId. However, the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/accept-reserved-instances-exchange-quote.html) does not mention whether this ID is the same as the new CRI ID, or where the ExchangeId can be used.

Is the ExchangeId the same as the ReservationId of new CRI? If not, is there a way we can use the ExchangeId to lookup the information of the new reservation that was created as a result of the exchange?